# linux удалить временные файлы программы

Tags: linux

Проблема с программой *audacity*: один раз она «повисла» и пришлось «убить» процесс. Теперь при каждом запуске выдаёт такое окно:

[image: audacity]

Восстановить проект не получается, куда я ни кликал и что ни нажимал. Закрываю окно и появляется такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И программа закрывается.

Пробовал удалить *audacity* (`apt-get remove audacity`, `apt-get purge audacity`), а потом заново установить, но не помогло.

Comment: Поищите ~/audacity или что-то типа того.

Comment: какое отношение к программе *audacity* имеет программа *linux*, которую вы упомянули в виде метки к вопросу?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. 

Такое отноешение, что audacity запускается в linux'е, и мне хотелось бы узнать, где хранятся в linux'е временные файлы программ, чтобы подчистить.

Comment: Вроде это `~/.audacity-data/AutoSave/`

Answer (score 4):

- Запустите программу.
- Зайдите в консоль и узнайте её pid ( например, ps -e | grep -i audacity ).
- Предположим это pid под номером 10000.
- lsof -p 10000 выдаст вам все открытые этим процессом файлы.

Либо вы можете запустить программу из консоли под strace:

```
strace -e trace=file [имя_программы]
```

и увидеть все операции с файлами. По выводу этой команды можно будет понять куда программа обращается за нужными ей файлами.

Answer (score 1):

Просто выполните в консоли.

```
rm -rf ~/.audacity-data/AutoSave/*
```

Если не поможет, то уж это поможет наверника.

```
rm -rf ~/.audacity-data
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один, не самый интеллектуальный, но надёжный метод - поискать сам этот "новый проект" на файловой системе: по имени файла с помощью find -type f, по содержимому файлов с любым именем с помощью grep -R. Найдёте файл - дальше, скорее всего, будет очевидно, что удалять.